# Work and Time problem for proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a_1$ men and $b_1$ boys can complete a work in $x$ days, while $a_2$ men and $b_2$ boys can complete the same work in $y$ days, then

$$\frac{\text{1 day work of 1 man}}{\text{1 day work of 1 boy}} = \frac{yb_2 - xb_1}{xa_1 - ya_1}
$$

Please help me out in proving this equation.

Comment: It's just proportions.  And where did the $yb2,xb1,xa1,ya1$ come from?  You haven't defined those.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your point.

Comment: My first point is that all these fractions means proportions are what is happening.  My second point is that you haven't told us what some of the variables mean.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the statement that I got.

Comment: Well, I suppose $yb2$ just means $y*b2$, where $y$ was defined to be the amount of days it took $a2$ men and $b2$ boys to complete the work (?) Not saying everything is crystal clear however, but I don't think I see any undefined variables.

Comment: @Christopher.L Yes, you are right mate.

Comment: Reformatted, but I think you need to fix the variables/subscripts in the last equation (which I didn't change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula -

(A men + B boys) $\times$ Number of days they work together = (C men + D boys) $\times$ Number of days they work together

$(a1 + b1) × x = (a2 + b2) × y$

$a1\cdot x + b1 \cdot x = a2\cdot y + b2 \cdot y$

$(a1\cdot x - a2 \cdot y)$ men = $(b2\cdot y - b1 \cdot x)$ boys

$\frac{\text{1 men}}{\text{1 boy}} = \frac{(b2\cdot y - b1 \cdot x)}{(a1\cdot x - a2 \cdot y)}$

Answer (score 2):

So you have two linear equations: in the following $s$ will denote the "amount of work" of one man per day and $t$ will denote the "amount of work" of one boy per day. 
\begin{align}
a_1\cdot s &+ b_1 \cdot t = x, \\
a_2\cdot s &+ b_2 \cdot t = y.
\end{align}
Using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule) we get that
$$
s=\frac{x\cdot b_2 - y\cdot b_1}{a_1\cdot b_2-a_2\cdot b_1}, \quad
t=\frac{x\cdot a_2 - y\cdot a_1}{a_1\cdot b_2-a_2\cdot b_1}.
$$
What you are looking for is then simply
$$
\frac{s}t =\frac{x\cdot b_2 - y\cdot b_1}{x\cdot a_2 - y\cdot a_1}.
$$